# Скачивание favicon с внешнего сайта

Tags: java, url, icon

В автоматическом режиме должно скачиваться favicon сайта который ввёл юзер.
К примеру я ввожу `http://google.com/`.
Далее, извлекаю из `head` ссылку на `shortcut icon`. Далее соединяю ссылку юзера и ссылку на иконку. Для google это так выглядит: `http://google.com/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico`.

Но. по этому пути файла нет. Выкидывает `FileNotFoundException`.

Подскажите как быть?

Пишу на Java.

Comment: Она в `http://www.google.com/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico` .... возможно надо перебирать вариант не только `subdomain.domain` но и `www.subdomain.domain`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский прикол в том что класс URL пишет ошибку если добавить `www`

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос код, который вы написали, для того, чтобы можно было проанализировать, что там так или не так

Comment: @АлексейШиманский всё. разобрался. заменяю `//` на `//www.`